# How to make Apache stop logging AH10244 [core:error] for 400 Bad Requests?

Tags: apache-2.4, logging

How do you make Apache (2.4.52) stop logging AH10244 [core:error]?

```
[Sun Mar 13 05:23:47.884213 2022] [core:error] [pid 558:tid 140262206592768] [client 45.146.165.37:51872] AH10244: invalid URI path (/cgi-bin/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/bin/sh)
[Tue Mar 15 10:19:35.439128 2022] [core:error] [pid 14291:tid 140557854676736] [client 45.77.75.45:37640] AH10244: invalid URI path (/%)
```

These log messages are caused by command line utilities (wget, curl, lynx) requesting ip address or vhost, e.g.

```
http://10.0.0.100/%
http://example.org/cgi-bin/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/bin/sh // note: a common attack vector
```

The only thing I've found to work so far is `LogLevel notice core:crit`, but I still want other `core:notice` messages to appear in my log, so that solution is a non-starter.

The answer very well may be, *it's not possible*. If so, please leave an answer letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LogLevel core:crit` is the only way to remove the `core:error` messages.

This could be fine-tuned by placing different `ErrorLog` and/or `LogLevel` directives in each vhost.